# Can't get formik validation to work with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, formik

Good morning,

I want a react-router link to forward ONLY when the form has no errors, unfortunately the code that's below does forward before the form is even validated so no error shows up and so on. Can you please guide me on how to fix this, so that the form is validated and if it has no errors, the link forwards further?

Here's my code:

```
<Link to={this.props.formikProps.isValid?'mainMenu': 'itemDetail'}>{!this.props.disabled && <button className="buttons-panel__button" type="button" onClick={() => (this.props.handleSubmit(false), this.props.formikProps.isValid? '' : this.onValidationFail())} >Save</button>}</Link>
```

The method is(it's basically only to display a popup error, and it's working):

```
onValidationFail() {
    setAlertMessage("You need to fill all mandatory fields")
}
```

So far the best I've achieved is that it works as intended in every case, but if the form hasn't been touched at all. I've tried several different ways, including formValidate from formik, for some reason it didn't work too.

I'm looking forward to some tips/hints/solutions on the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your solution looks bit overcomplicated. Maybe just use simple form submit, and after form submission redirect user to route.
It would look like that:

```
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik'

class MyForm {
  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={...}
        onSubmit={() => {this.props.history.push('/go-somewhere')}}
      >
        <Form>
          <Field name="firstName" type="text" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The component that I'm using is a class and it has to stay that way, so I believe the solution is a no go(despite looking to be pretty solid to me).

Comment: Class component is no problem. I have updated answer for class example.

Comment: Well I have used BrowserRouter, and added that to the method:
onSubmit={useHistory('/address')}>

It doesn't work. I'm new to react, but as far as I read the history is automatically implemented, and this should work the same way as Router history={History} and then this.props.history.push('address').

Comment: But `useHistory` is a hook appropriate for functional component. In class component you can use `this.props.history.push("address")`

Comment: Unfortunately it throws an error: 
"Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly<IManualAdjustmentFormikWrapperProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)"
And the history part is always underlined.